# BigQuery get column as comma seperated values

Tags: google-bigquery

Is there a Bigquery equivalent of SQLServer STUFF function to get a field as comma seperated values instead of multiple rows?

For example

```
**Table 1**
id  name
1   John
2   John
3   Tom
1   Harry
4   Harry
5   Harry
```

```
**Table 2**
id  group
1   group1
2   group2
3   group3
4   group4
5   group5
```

I want the result to be

```
name    group
John    group1,group2
Tom     group3
Harry   group1,group4,group5
```

Thanks in advance for the help

Comment: Can you please fix the formatting of `Table 1` and `Table 2`? It's not clear what the column names are versus the contents of the rows.

Comment: fixed the table formatting. sorry about that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With standard SQL:

```
#standardSQL
SELECT name, STRING_AGG(DISTINCT `group` ORDER BY `group`) 
FROM (table or sub-select doing join)
GROUP BY name
```

Comment: (`group` is a reserved keyword, as a heads up, so it may be necessary to escape that column name with backticks in the query)